# ssh connecting timeouts from a to b, but works from a to c, and c to b

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshfs

I am scratching my head here.  I now get timeouts between hosts `A` and `B`, both running Ubuntu, with some firewall NATing on either side and a good dozen hops in between. (To clarify based on the first comment:  The initial connection fails and 'hangs'; this may be after another (existing) connection ended.)

Yet I can also connect using ssh from `A` to another host on another subnet, call it `C` and then connect from `C` to `B` just fine.  So it should not be the ssh server settings.  The alternate route also works for a second host `D`, also on another subnet.

But the trouble is that my main workstation often just sits there when trying to connect.  The only related issue I can think of is that I am also (sometimes) using `sshfs` between A and B.

One idea as to how I can address this?

Comment: Do you mean a timeout as in it doesn't connect, or a timeout in that the connection stops after working for a while?

Comment: I am more concerned about the former.  It just sits there at about line 4 under `ssh -v` and nothing happens.  Whereas I can go the alternate route.   The odd thing is that the timeout seems to affect all possibly clients on my home network.  Yet I had the same NAT setup for many years.

Comment: Is your IP static?  Could it have been blocked on the server?

Comment: No, and "eventually" this resolves after maybe 20 or so minutes. But I do not recall adding a configuration on either side that would enforce this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how far it is getting.  Can you do a `sudo  traceroute -P tcp -p 22 <server B IP>`

Comment: `traceroute` doesn't quite make it all the way, whether I add the -p/-P args or not (which is how I ran it). It also does not work back from B to A -- so there could be a firewall issue at B's end. And that is with the `ssh` session is up/remained up for the last 12+ hours.

Comment: Yes, something in the path is blocking it.  You can pinpoint it by doing the same command from C to B.  It might be a transient routing issue, which if it doesn't impact many people, might go unnoticed.  So identifying where it gets lost will help your ISP contact the right people.

Comment: The weird thing this that it seems fine for as long as I don't touch sshfs.

Comment: Nope, now I got a timeout without touching sshfs.  And while I can't get from A to B right now, I can do A->C->B and then connect back from B to A. Weird.